# What do round brackets mean here? React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Here is a custom input component

```
const Input = ({props}) => {
    return (
        <input type="text" {...props} {...props.reg}/>
    );
};
```

I passed a React Hook Form register function to this custom Input.

```
        <Input props={{
            placeholder: 'Name',
            id: 'form__name',
            name: 'name',
            reg: {...(register('name'), {required: true})}
        }}/>
```

Input was registered and I was not able to figure out what do round brackets before the spread operator mean.

What kind of JS/React syntax is it? **...(xxx, xxx)**

P.S. this line of code

```
reg: {...(register('name'), {required: true})}
```

was taken from some youtube video, I just rewrote it, but round brackets before spread operator were still used in the video

Comment: What does the Register function return exactly?

Comment: Andreas, it is not that part they are asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator is rarely used in this way but essentially, if you do this:

```
statment1, statement2
```

Then the second statement is returned. However, `statment1` is executed, just not returned.

Here it's used to register the field but the result of the statement inside the brackets is actually just `{required: true}`.

The brackets themselves just enclose this inner comma statement. The inside of the brackets is evaluated first, and the result of that is then spread.

More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: There are two instances of `statment1` here - should that have been `statement1`?